# How to connect Opencart with another Opencart through API

Tags: php, json, opencart, opencart2.x

I have an small store that sells VOIP phones. I want to populate it's database from our provider. They use Opencart too and gave us an username and password to get API access. the API, as usual, returns content in JSON. I've been searching but couldn't find any way to import from provider's Opencart API to my site.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenCart native API doesn't have any functionality for this sort of thing. It's incomplete as of now.

If your provider has built this functionality themselves you'll need to get an SDK from them or roll your own based on their endpoints.

Comment: I see, well, i had hope on this to be achieved but i'll have to do an script to handle this manually. Thanks